# Sound not working after installing 14.04 from mini CD image

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm working with a clean install of 14.04, but because my USB ports are broken and I didn't have a spare DVD handy I've installed from the mini CD image.

The only problem I've had is that the sound doesn't work. I've installed and reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa but still nothing.

Here is the output from my alsainfo: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=9d2d104a55b5bf0b0114d22fdae77aadbdd49751

I've never really had a problem with sound on Ubuntu at all, it's always just worked, so I've never taken the time to learn about it. What sorts of things should I be looking at in order to problem solve this?

EDIT: Just noticed that the mixer for pulseaudio is only listing HDMI outputs and not my stereo jack output (unsure what that output is normally listed as). I just tested the HDMI output and the sound can only be heard when I change the volume on the TV it's plugged into and even then it's glitchy. Once I stop moving the volume up or down it disappears again. Really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to resolve this issue now and I'll post how I did it in case anyone stumbles across this on Google at any point:

In my case I'd neglected to install speech-dispatcher upon installation. The minimum CD does not include this, as you'd probably expect. Simply run:

`sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher`

If you're still having trouble also run:

`sudo apt-get install alsa-base alsa-utils alsa-tools
sudo apt-get install libasound2 libasound2-plugins
sudo alsa force-reload`